# Global variables not acting like local variables?

Tags: bash, shell, variables, global, local

I have two bash scripts. Script1 does the following (doesn't matter why I'm using two scripts; just assume it's for a good reason):

```
export RUN=1
```

And script2:

```
. script1
echo ${RUN}
sed -n ${RUN}p mytext.txt > mytextnew.txt
```

In script 2, echo returns "1" as I expect. However, the sed command (or any other command I try and use the RUN variable with) returns an error, as if RUN doesn't exist. If I simply run script2 with the following:

```
RUN=2p
sed -n ${RUN} mytext.txt > mytextnew.txt
```

then everything works fine. This *only* happens with global variables. If I do the exact same thing I do with local variables that I do with global variables, everything works. But the minute a global variable is thrown in there, everything goes haywire.

Any insight into the problem?

Comment: you mean `. script1` (with space, right?) and the sed will not return error if the RUN isn;t defined, simply will execute the `sed -n p` what will print all lines... so if throws error, here is another problem.

Comment: Yes definitely, thanks for catching that.

Comment: are you sure than your script doesn;t contains `\r` (e.g. Windows line endings?) in this case the RUN will get a value `1\r` and this will throw error (of course)....

Comment: wouldn't echo ${RUN} output '1\r' if that's the case? In my case it outputs the correct thing (1).

Comment: No, because the shell would swallow the extra "whitespace" that the `\r` is encoding and echo wouldn't ever see it. Try `echo "${RUN}"` or `echo "-${RUN}-"` instead. `\r` isn't two characters but an escape sequence for carriage-return.

Comment: @user1566200 The [bash tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info) explains how to look for carriage returns in your files and data.

Comment: Just tried that; outputs -1-, so it doesn't look like Windows line endings are the problem.

Comment: Which error message do you actually get?

Comment: Try `hexdump` or `uniname` to get a nice view of the binary contents of the scripts. There might be something else wrong.

Comment: PS: [Use More Quotes™](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes). Curly brackets are not enough.

Comment: I get the error "sed: -e expression #1, char 1: missing command"

Comment: you have a space between the `1 p`... so, in your script you have `sed ${RUN} p` what is (again ofcourse) error... or your $RUN is defined like `RUN="1 "`, see - run the script as `bash -x script2` and will see...

Answer (score 0):

The following:

```
$ cat script1
export RUN=1

$cat script2
. script1
echo ${RUN}
sed -n ${RUN}p /etc/passwd
```

after the

```
$ bash -x script2
```

prints

```
+ . script1
++ export RUN=1
++ RUN=1
+ echo 1
1
+ sed -n 1p /etc/passwd
```

if adding the space to

```
sed -n ${RUN} p /etc/passwd
```

prints

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 1: missing command
```

check the content of the $RUN with

```
echo "${RUN}" | od -bc    #note the double quotes
#or
echo "${RUN}" | xxd
```

to see, what really contains your `$RUN` variable...

Comment: When I run `echo "${RUNLINE}"`, I get 0000000 062 012 (2 \n)